# Prototyping struct in Go

Tags: go

My use case is, I need to have several structs in Go, who will have methods of same signatures and not necessarily have to have all the methods. The following code describes the requirements and also represents my current solution.

```
type calc struct {
    fn func(a, b int) int
    gn func(a string) bool
    name string
}

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func bar(foo string) bool {
    // do something
}

func sub(a, b int) int {
    return a - b
}

func main() {
    for c := range []calc{{
        fn: add,
        gn: bar,
        name: "addition",
    }, {
        fn: sub,
        name: "subtraction",
    }} {
        fmt.Printf("%s(10, 15) returned: %d\n", c.name, c.fn(10, 15))
        if c.gn != nil {
            c.gn(c.name)
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to improve this code? What's the best way to achieve this in Go? Can I achieve a better solution using interface?

Comment: What is `c.foo` and where does `gn` (the function, not method) come from?

Comment: @Ainar-G Ah sorry, updated

Answer (score 4):

Use interfaces.

```
type Op interface {
    Name() string
    Do(a, b int) int
}

type Add struct{}

func (Add) Name() string    { return "add" }
func (Add) Do(a, b int) int { return a + b }

type Sub struct{}

func (Sub) Name() string    { return "sub" }
func (Sub) Do(a, b int) int { return a - b }
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/LjJt6D0hNF.

---

**EDIT:** Since you've edited your question, here is an example of how you could use asserting and interface to a broader interface for your task:

```
type RevOp interface {
    Op
    ReverseDo(a, b int) int
}

// ...

func (Add) ReverseDo(a, b int) int { return a - b }

// ...

fmt.Printf("%s(10, 15) returned: %d\n", op.Name(), op.Do(10, 15))
if op, ok := op.(RevOp); ok {
    fmt.Printf("reverse of %s(10, 15) returned: %d\n", op.Name(), op.ReverseDo(10, 15))
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/MQ6LlPDcEi.

Comment: I know this solution, but I'm confused if this is an improvement to that. I kind of don't like this way as we need to have an extra function to set/get the values of struct fields.
Is there any certain go-pher logic for which this version is better than my dummy code?

Comment: @Fallen without a concrete example of what you have *and* what you would like, I don't think you can get a better solution. Your dummy example seems like the perfect use-case for interfaces.

Comment: I think the main functional difference between the two is that if you have a variable that holds a function (op's code), the variable can be `nil` and uncallable, but if you're trying to make a struct that will use the interface then either the struct will have the function or it won't match the interface (i.e. if it matches the interface, then you know the function has to be defined and callable)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Right you are. Sorry for not having "not necessarily have to have all the methods" type of example. have just added one. So in this case, an interface will fail to provide what I want to have.

Comment: @Ainar-G: Your solution looks good. But I'm still not convinced why it's better than the solution in the question. Is there any golang philosophy or design related flaws? Thanks :)

Comment: @Fallen The big difference is that your `fv` and `gn` fields are just _fields_, not methods. Your `c.fv()` is not a method call, it's just a function call, calling the function value of the `fv` field of the `c` struct whose type is `calc`. With your solution, you lose the flexibility of Go's interface system. E.g. noone will be able to convert your type to an interface like this: `type Doer interface{ Do(a, b int) int }`. While Ainar-G's values of `Op` types can be.

Answer (score 0):

I've discussed with some people in person and apparently my solution was correct. While it can be rewritten using interface, that's not necessarily an improvement.